# WPF Application Slow Unresponsive when demonstrating using remote sharing software

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

After spending 14 hours on this I think its time to share my woes and see if anyone has experienced this issue before.

Ill describe the issue and tests I have done to rule out certain things.

Ok so I have a WPF application which loads in data from an SQL database. 
I am using DevExpress Components for datagrids, ribbons etc.. and FluentNhibernate to provide a session for database operations. I am also using log4net to log events to a textfile.

Using the application on my laptop with SQL Express 2008 works fine.. the application starts up, retrieves 1000 records and I can tab through the controls on the ribbon.

Now, I decided to demo the application to a third party and used remote login/sharing software online to share my desktop with the other person so as I could load the application on my laptop and they could view me using the application.

Now, the application takes approx 45 seconds to load... 30 seconds with a blank database where as, when im not sharing out my screen using the online software the application loads in about 7-10 seconds. As well as that, even using the controls in the application during the demo were very sticky, slow and unresponsive.

During the sharing session though however I was able to use other applications without any problems.. everything else worked fine.

But I cannot understand how my application works ok under normal conditions , even browsing the net at the same time etc... BUT totally fails to perform correctly when I am sharing a session with another user... the CPU usage shot up to 100% too at times when the application was trying to start up...

Please see below a list of 3rd party dlls I am using as references in my project.

- DevExpress dlls
- FluidKit
- PixelLab.WPF
- PixelLab.Common
- Galasoft WPF Kit
- FluentNHibernate
- NHibernate
- Nhibernate.ByteCode.Castle
- Skype4ComLib
- TXTEXTControl
- log4net
- LinqKit

All of these DLLs are in the output folder with the application dlls created from the class assemblys in the project. So when installed via an installer on a machine the dlls will be in the same application folder as the application file itself.

Many thanks

Comment: Please list the remote desktop application you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw something similar about a year ago with logmein. The performance is not the app its the graphics processing .  WPF renders graphically in a completely different way then GDI winforms see around 2.3 and down [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480192.aspx).  Many remote desktop application have trouble rendering this correctly particularly if you don't use the plug ins (say logmein).  You didn't say what you were using but I would suggest trying a few different RDP options as there are many out there, and making sure your on the newest versions.

Comment: Hi Adam / Hi bumble_bee_tuna, thanks for taking the time to check my question out and respond... the remote software being used to share the demo session is 'NTRSupport'.. Adam, that certainly does make sense now you say it... I would assume this would be the same as logmein then ?

Comment: bumble_bee_tuna mate, much appreciation for your answer... this has helped tremendously... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [bumle-bee-tuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574663/bumble-bee-tuna) points out, WPF will default to software rendering over Remote Desktop. Another way may be to screen share using Skype or similar. This means you'll be rendering the app locally but transmitting an image to the remote user. the app should work at full speed and the only lag the viewer will see will be introduced by the Skype network. I've used this technique many times to deliver presentations remotely and works well!

Comment: No problems, glad to be of help :)